# why BeanDefinition.getPropertyValues return an empty list

Tags: spring, annotations, empty-list

I configured spring with `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.  While I called `BeanDefinition.getPropertyValues()` in a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` implementation , I got an empty list . But if i configured spring with `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext`, it return the right value.  Does anyone know the reason?

Here is my codes:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public BeanFactoryPostProcessorTest beanFactoryPostProcessorTest(){
        return new BeanFactoryPostProcessorTest();
    }

    @Bean
    public Person person(){
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("name");
        person.setAge(18);
        return person;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BeanFactoryPostProcessorTest implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor{
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        BeanDefinition bd = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition("person");
        MutablePropertyValues propertyValues = bd.getPropertyValues();
        if(propertyValues.contains("name")){
            propertyValues.addPropertyValue("name","zhangfei");
        }
        System.out.println("Factory modfy zhangfei");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        /*ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");*/
        Person person = context.getBean(Person.class);
        System.out.println(person.getName());
    }
}
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: From the java doc of BeanFactoryPostProcessor, **A BeanFactoryPostProcessor may interact with and modify bean definitions, but never bean instances.**. You are trying to modify an instance, rather than a definition. Wondering if this is the right interface that you need to use ..

Comment: thanks for your help . while i read the doc i had the same thought as you. so i try to search the difference between BeanFactoryPostProcessor and BeanPostProcessor, they all gave the same expample code as i gave above . so i tried it myself and find the problem . i have two questions.
1. how to use BeanFactoryPostProcessor? how can i modify beandefinition?
2. as i descripted above.why i got an empty list after BeanDefinition.getPropertyValues() ?

thanks.

Comment: ok .. so hopefully my solution will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got a null list simply because the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is called before the instances are created and assigned values. They will be called before the instance creation.

I have done the same thing which you were trying to do using a different interface. Use the `BeanPostProcessor` interface.

```
public class BeanPostProcessorTest implements BeanPostProcessor{
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name)
            throws BeansException {
        if("person".equals(name)){
            Person person =((Person)bean);          
            if("name".equals(person.getName())){
                person.setName("zhangfei");
            }
            return person;
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object arg0, String arg1)
            throws BeansException {
        return arg0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can do this by reflection . but i want to know why i got an empty list after i  call BeanDefinition.getPropertyValues() ? but thank u all the same.

Comment: Modified the answer. Can you please accept the answer if this does solve your problem